# Smooth font rendering for Japanese characters

Tags: windows-7, fonts, rendering, cleartype, font-smoothing

I am using Windows 7 and have set font smoothing to ClearType. However, Japanese characters display very roughly throughout the operating system. What can I do so they are rendered smoothly like other characters?

Here is a sample of what they currently look like:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are Japanese characters rendered roughly only in your web browser? If so, which browser are you using?

Comment: @iglvzx, I use Chrome. But the problem is not limited to Chrome. Wordpad, Word etc behave the same.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clarifying. I will add this information to your question. :)

Comment: by the way, it is not the "hiragana" that remembered something, it is you who remembered the hiragana. the correct phrase is "ひらがなを覚えた"

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that traditional Japanese fonts (MS Gothic, MS PGothic, MS Mincho…) also include *bitmap* fonts in small sizes in addition to outline ones (typically for characters 22pt and less). These bitmaps **cannot be applied any type of smoothing**, so it results in a crazily ugly aliasing, eye hurting appearance. There are several solutions for this:

- [Mactype](http://www.mactype.net/) is an **[open source](https://github.com/snowie2000/mactype) replacement** (among others, but right now it's the most updated) **for Windows font renderer** based on [FreeType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeType#Other_users). It will just skip those bitmaps and use the outlines to output smooth characters.

  But currently Mactype cannot emulate *DirectDraw* calls, so some programs that use *DirectDraw/DirectWrite* (such as MS office 2013, IE7+, Firefox…) still have aliased fonts, but this is quite rare. On Google Chrome you need to [disable DirectWrite](http://www.sihmar.com/2016/04/05/install-mactype-fonts-windows-guide/) to make it work

  **Update:** The latest Mactype already has better DirectWrite support

  More on this: [How To Make Windows Fonts Look Like Mac Fonts](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/make-windows-fonts-look-like-mac-fonts/)

  [image: mactype]
- A better option is **stripping all those bitmaps off** according to [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20160402134225/http://tomtia.plala.jp/pc/ttfont/). You need some Japanese ability to read it but you can also read the [rough translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ja&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.archive.org%2Fweb%2F20160402134225%2Fhttp%3A%2F%2Ftomtia.plala.jp%2Fpc%2Fttfont%2F&edit-text=&act=url) from Google. The steps to do is quite long so please find it at the end. The result is:

  - [No antialiasing with bitmap font](http://tomtia.plala.jp/PC/ttfont/images/ieaa01.gif) (default for Japanese characters less than 23pt)
    [image: アンチエイリアシングなし]
  - [Cleartype](http://tomtia.plala.jp/PC/ttfont/images/ieaa02.gif) after stripping bitmaps
    [image: ClearTypeを使用]
  - [Standard antialiasing](http://tomtia.plala.jp/PC/ttfont/images/ieaa03.gif) after stripping bitmaps
    [image: 標準アンチエイリアシング]
  - [No bitmap (outline), no antialiasing](http://tomtia.plala.jp/PC/ttfont/images/ieaa04.gif)
    [image: おまけ]

## Steps to strip bitmaps from fonts:

- Copy the fonts files you need to strip, for example *msgothic.ttc*, from `\Windows\Fonts` into a folder
- Download the [`BREAKTTC` tool from MS TrueType SDK](https://www.xlsoft.com/jp/products/indigorose/autoplay_readme_02.html)
- Open a command prompt in the folder you copied the fonts to and type `BREAKTTC msgothic.ttc`. After that you can see all the ttf files in the ttc are extracted as *FONT00.ttf ~ FONTxx.ttf*

  [image: breakttc]
- Now you to download the [FontTools](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/f/a/ffae9ec6-3bf6-488a-843d-b96d552fd815/FontTools.exe) from [Microsoft Typography](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/tools.aspx). After that extract the `SBIT32` tool which is needed to remove the EBDT (Embedded bitmap data table). The command syntax is as below

  ```bat
  SBIT32 -d <original font file> <metric file> [output file]
  ```

  You need to run this for each bitmap sizes (typically from 7 to 22) to remove all bitmaps, which is rather clumsy if typing by hand. An automated script would be of great help.

  ```bat
  @echo off
  copy %1 %2 >nul
  for /l %%i in ( 7,1,22 ) do (
      echo PPEM %%i > mtemp.txt
      echo END >> mtemp.txt
      sbit32 -d %2 mtemp.txt ftemp.ttf  
      del %2
      ren ftemp.ttf %2
  )
  del mtemp.txt
  ```

  Save the above content as `rmEBDT.bat` and run the following commands (3 for MS Gothic because we have 3 extracted ttf files)

  ```bat
  rmEBDT font00.ttf msgot2.ttf　
  rmEBDT font01.ttf msgotp2.ttf　
  rmEBDT font02.ttf msuigot2.ttf
  ```
- Now we have stripped font files, we can rename those font names (which is independent from *font file names*), like to MS Gothic NB - *No Bitmap*, to use alongside with the old fonts, or just use the old name and replace the original ttc file, which is a little tricker.
  Either way we need to pack them again to a ttc file in order to install back to Windows. Use the tool `MAKETTC` which is in the same folder as `BREAKTTC` or you can also find them [here](http://sookie.eek.jp/wiki/%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB/ttsdk). Run

  ```bat
  MAKETTC <TTC output file name> <TTF file 1> <TTF file 2> ...
  ```
- After getting the ttc file, if you have changed the font name you just directly copy them to `\Windows\Fonts` to register it as a new font and change the default font in UI, apps... to that font. If you want to use the old font name you must boot from another OS like Linux live USB or Windows PE because Windows always load MS Gothic at boot time.

Comment: Five posts in three hours by a new user on this site recommending the same program. Looks too spammy. Please don't do that. Are you affiliated with the software developers in some way?

Comment: Just answer a question and then find out some related question so I answer them too. Is that prohibited?

Comment: No. Unfortunately there are spammers, and their behavior is basically identical, advertising their own software on a bunch of similar questions. Moderators then need to determine whether it's legitimate advice, or spam. We sometimes make mistakes though and consider enthusiasts to be spammers. The previous comment was more of a suggestion to prevent your posts from mistakenly getting deleted.

Comment: It would sure be nice if Microsoft would just provide an option to disable the use of the bitmaps in those fonts.

Comment: @Wyck they did that in Windows 8 RC. I don't know if they removed the bitmaps or ignored them but texts are crisp, beautiful and clear. But somehow in the official release the bitmaps are used again and the text came back ugly as a pain in the \*ss

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the font. Different fonts have different characteristics, including different behavior in font smoothing. You might be using a font in the Mincho group, as they are commonly used as default fonts and they may have problems like this; Gothic fonts may work better on screen.

Comment: How do I switch my font style for Japanese characters alone?

Comment: @missingfaktor, that depends on the program being used; and normally you should not switch font style by language but instead select a font that is acceptable for all characters you need. When using Word, this might be Arial Unicode MS, if it’s OK to use such a sans-serif font of simple design–it has a very wide character coverage.

Answer (score 2):

[Meiryo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiryo), the default Japanese font for Windows Vista/7, as well as some other Japanese fonts contain bitmap (pixel) characters at small sizes.

Going back to your example, I was able to confirm this using Firefox:

- ClearType (hinted) characters:

  [image: hinted]
- Smaller font-size; bitmap characters:

  [image: bitmap]

---

By default, Firefox uses the following settings for Japanese fonts:

[image: font settings]

---

So, the solution lies in using larger font sizes or replacing the default Japanese font uses in an application with one that supports hinted characters for all sizes (e.g. **Arial Unicode**).

To globally remap/substitute a font in Windows, you can modify or add [Registry values](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102960) under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes
```

Comment: In my example, you can notice that Kanji are rendered smoothly, while Kana aren't.

Comment: I assume that is due to a minor discrepancy in font size or browser settings. I used Firefox, while your example is in Google Chrome.

Comment: No, Meiryo contains no bitmaps, as it was already designed for font smoothing, therefore it's always beautiful in any font sizes. You just need to change the default Japanese font to Meiryo. Only the old fonts with bitmaps are awful. `It was decided that a new Japanese font was needed, as the current ones (mainly MS Gothic and MS Mincho) are incompatible with Microsoft's ClearType subpixel rendering technology[citation needed]: Meiryo is intended to increase legibility of characters on LCD screens`

Comment: `Unlike previous fonts designed for CJK environments, Meiryo contains no embedded bitmaps. To improve readability under small font sizes without using embedded bitmaps, TrueType hinting language was used for stroke-reduction. Similar technology was used on MingLiU and PMingLiU versions 5.03.` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiryo#Characteristics

Comment: absolutely, I've experienced that Meiryo actually fixes everything. I don't know why windows (even 10) in 2017 still uses 1990's tech by default and is happy with it.

Comment: @v.oddou MS did fixed that in Windows 8 RC, all Japanese texts are smooth. But probably it caused some guys to irritate so they reported it and MS reverted the change in the official release so Japanese texts became broken again